# linqjs intersect comparer issue

Tags: javascript, linq.js

I am using linqjs and I have one array full of ids to include in a list, and an array full of complex objects which have a property `userId`.

Problem is when I do an intersection it never seems to return anything, however there is very little information around the `compareSelector`.

So here is an example of what I am doing:

```
enumerableOfUsers.intersect(listOfIdsToInclude, "$.userId");
```

So in the above example `enumerableOfUsers` would be an existing enumerable created from an array of users (which contain the `userId` field), the `listOfIdsToInclude` is an array of id values, like `["12345", "213213", "2124"]` etc.

The intersect seems to work but never returns anything and I know the userIds match so am I doing anything wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that the compare selector is applied to items of both the first and second sets.  The second set is a list of ids already so the compare selector doesn't apply.  The projection yields `undefined` values which will always result in no results found.

You need to apply the selector only to the first set of values.  Try this instead:

```
// using linqjs 2.x syntax
var query = enumerableOfUsers.Select("$.userId").Intersect(listOfIdsToInclude);
```

Comment: Ah ok brilliant that makes some sense, however this does mean that after intersecting I lose the rest of the user object, is there any other approach which would keep the entire user object in scope of the query so I can return them back out the other end? I am basically using this like a `where( x=> x.userId is in listOfIdsToInclude)`... maybe I can just do a where with an indexOf or something instead of an intersect. Anyway you get the answer as this provides the info needed.

Comment: In that case, I would use a join instead. On the other hand, the equivalent of a `where value in collection` can be achieved by using `collection.Contains(value)`. You won't be able to express that in a lambda string however.